# Python Telebot (Telegram) How to delete auto attached preview of link?

Tags: python, telegram

I send message with link. But Telegram automatically add preview of link. How can I cancel this action? I want to see only my link.

[image: Attached link]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `disable_web_page_preview=True`:

```
bot.send_message(chat_id, '[olo](https://vk.com/im)', parse_mode= 'Markdown', disable_web_page_preview=True)
```